# I get wrong output when using diff -u between two textfiles

Tags: bash, git-bash

When i use "diff -u" between two txt files where I have only changed two lines it tells me that i've changed every line in the file. Here's the output:

```
 Admin@DESKTOP-9A5CFG4 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/singlediff
$ diff -u nutty-pancake.txt nutty-pancake-new.txt
--- nutty-pancake.txt   2016-07-12 16:48:29.465917000 +0200
+++ nutty-pancake-new.txt       2016-07-12 16:49:10.737818500 +0200
@@ -1,61 +1,61 @@
-Nutty Pancake
-
-== Ingredients ==
-
-* 1 cup all-purpose bleached flour
-* 2 teaspoons sugar
-* 1/2 teaspoon salt
-* 1/3 teaspoon baking powder
-* 1/4 teaspoon baking soda
-* 3/4 cup buttermilk
-* 1/4 cup milk
-* 1 large egg
-* 2 tablespoon unsalted butter, melted
-* 1 teaspoon almond extract
-* Vegetable oil for brushing griddle
-
-== Procedure ==
-
-1. Heat a large non-stick skillet or griddle over
-   low heat while preparing ingredients.
-
-2. Mix flour, sugar, salt, baking powder, and baking
-   soda in medium bowl.
-
-3. Microwave buttermilk and milk in a 2-cup Pyrex
-   measuring cup to room temperature, 20 to 30 seconds.
-
-4. Whisk in egg, butter, and almond extract.
-
-5. Add wet ingredients to dry ingredients and whisk until
-   just mixed.
-
-6. Return batter to measuring cup, stirring in a teaspoon
-   or two of water, if necessary, to make a thick, but pourable batter.
-
-7. Increase heat to medium and generously brush skillet or griddle with
-   oil.
-
-8. When oil starts to spider, but before it starts to smoke, pour
-   batter, about 1/4 cup at a time.
-
-9. Work in batches, if necessary, to avoid overcrowding.
-
-10. When pancake bottoms are golden brown and tops start to bubble,
-    2 to 3 minutes, flip pancakes.
-
-11. Cook until pancakes are golden brown on remaining side.
-
-12. Repeat, brushing skillet or griddle with oil.
-
-Serve hot.
-
-==Source==
-
-This recipe originally comes from Wikibooks.
-
-http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?oldid=769489
-(last visited May 19, 2012).
-
-Some rights reserved; see http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
-for more information.
+Nutty Pancake
+
+== Ingredients ==
+
+* 1 cup all-purpose bleached flour
+* 2 teaspoons sugar
+* 1/2 teaspoon salt
+* 1/3 teaspoon baking powder
+* 1/4 teaspoon baking soda
+* 3/4 cup buttermilk
+* 1/4 cup milk
+* 1 large egg
+* 2 tablespoon unsalted butter, melted
+* 1 teaspoon walnut extract
+* Vegetable oil for brushing griddle
+
+== Procedure ==
+
+1. Heat a large non-stick skillet or griddle over
+   low heat while preparing ingredients.
+
+2. Mix flour, sugar, salt, baking powder, and baking
+   soda in medium bowl.
+
+3. Microwave buttermilk and milk in a 2-cup Pyrex
+   measuring cup to room temperature, 20 to 30 seconds.
+
+4. Whisk in egg, butter, and walnut extract.
+
+5. Add wet ingredients to dry ingredients and whisk until
+   just mixed.
+
+6. Return batter to measuring cup, stirring in a teaspoon
+   or two of water, if necessary, to make a thick, but pourable batter.
+
+7. Increase heat to medium and generously brush skillet or griddle with
+   oil.
+
+8. When oil starts to spider, but before it starts to smoke, pour
+   batter, about 1/4 cup at a time.
+
+9. Work in batches, if necessary, to avoid overcrowding.
+
+10. When pancake bottoms are golden brown and tops start to bubble,
+    2 to 3 minutes, flip pancakes.
+
+11. Cook until pancakes are golden brown on remaining side.
+
+12. Repeat, brushing skillet or griddle with oil.
+
+Serve hot.
+
+==Source==
+
+This recipe originally comes from Wikibooks.
+
+http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?oldid=769489
+(last visited May 19, 2012).
+
+Some rights reserved; see http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
+for more information.
```

I have only changed two occurrences of the word almond to walnut.
I am using gitbash in windows by the way.

Comment: Sounds like you've opened your file in a Windows text editor, which has replaced all the line endings for you.

Comment: There might be options to your version of `diff` that will let you ignore changes in whitespace or trailing carriage returns.

Comment: I edited the file using sublime instead of notepad and it solved the problem , Thanks!

Comment: If you're using `GNU diff`, use the `--strip-trailing-cr` option. You can also use the `-w` option to ignore other whitespace changes.